# exec command in java

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

If i am using following command in java:

```
Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("some .exe file of VB");
```

How do I know that the particular .exe has done its job  eg: it executed successfully.

How do i know that it has some error or just completed half task in java.
How should I design my program in java to know or Is there any way to tell java from VB.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I would assume that you could look at the exit status of the program: `ps.exitValue()` or you could read the stdout/stderr `ps.getInputStream()` / `ps.getErrorStream()` respectively.

Comment: +1, Though you MUST read the stdout/stderr; whether you pay attention to it after reading it is up to you :-).

Comment: @Mark True, that's a whole other series of SO questions.  Thanks for the edit, I didn't read the API close enough.

Answer (score 2):

You get back a Process

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Which has such methods as:

```
exitValue() 
getErrorStream() 
waitFor()
```

Which will get you what you need