# force create a directory using bash command through java code

Tags: java, linux, bash, sh

I am in some trouble. I am trying to force create a folder using bash command through java code in linux server. My code is as followes-

```
String command = "/root/new_scripts/makedir.sh /webroot/Own";
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runtime.exec(command);
        return "true";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return ex.toString();
    }
```

and the makedir.sh files contains

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir $1
```

But it cannt create a directory.

And also try to create a directory just using java code is as following-

```
String s = null;
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mkdir /webroot/Own");
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("\n\n\nHere is the standard output of the command:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\nexception happened - here's what I know: ");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it gives me the following error-

Here is the standard output of the command:

Here is the standard error of the command (if any):

mkdir: cannot create directory `/webroot/Own': Permission denied

Comment: Please, capture the output of the process to stdout and stderr and provide it in your post as well. And process exit code as well.

Comment: Hint: you don't need to call the external script, as mkdir is an executable in Linux. Simply use command `mkdir /webroot/v3custompritom`.

Comment: String command = "mkdir /webroot/v3";//
            try {
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process process = runtime.exec(command);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                
            }

Comment: Trsy `strace`-ing your Java VM; you'll understand why your `mkdir` fails.

Comment: @Pritom: You haven't updated your question as I've asked in my first comment. Checkout the same advise [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3209770/267197), and solutions [here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016) and more correct [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3350862/267197).

Comment: Hey man, I have edited my question, please take a look at it. It does not give me permission to create a directory, but I want to create a directory forcely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your project directory permissions: `chmod +w /<your project directory>` then use `mkdir` command.

Comment: That would not possible, Have please any other idea to force create a directory like force delete directory?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the  [mkdir](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/mkdirexamples.htm) function of Java which calls directly the [mkdir](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) system call?

It probably fails because of permission issues.

Comment: If the syscall failed, it gave you an error code explaining why.

Answer (score 1):

Handling the output of a process in Java is not the easiest thing to do. If it is for debugginh only, I would modify `makedir.sh` like so;

```
mkdir $2 > err.txt 2>err.txt
```

Run your java code and then check err.txt- expect to find something like `permission denied` in there. For production code, you would like your java app to be aware of the failure of `makedir.sh`. Look at [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) great article for tips on how to read the process' stream correctly.

Comment: It is for permission denied, but is there any way to force create the folder?